# Access to ref in component from same level component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs3

I have the following structure:

[image]

I need to access the ref into D component from component E. If I try to do it from parent A I get the information:

```js
this.$refs['ref_to_D']; // <-- This works
```

But if I try to do it from component B using parent, it returns undefined.

```js
this.$parent.$refs['ref_to_D']; // <-- Not works, print undefined
```

The diagram is simplified, I leave the most complete code below.

(A) Parent:

```js
<template>
  <!-- Base Table (B)-->
  <base-table>
    <template #head>
      <base-cell tag="th">ID</base-cell>
      <base-cell tag="th">Name</base-cell>
    </template>
    <!-- Base table slot #body (C) -->
    <template #body>
      <!-- tr tag rendered with v-for -->
      <tr
        v-for="(user, index) in users"
        :key="user.id"
        :class="{ 'striped-row': (index + 1) % 2 == 0 }"
      >
        <base-cell tag="td">
          {{ user.id }}
        </base-cell>
        <base-cell tag="td">
          {{ user.name }}
        </base-cell>
        <!-- Green block -->
        <base-cell tag="td">
          <!-- Base Button: (D) Component -->
          <base-button 
            @click="togglePopover(user.id)"
            :ref="`${user.id}-user-actions`"
          >
            <base-icon icon="user" />
          </base-button>
          <!-- Base Popover: (E) Component -->
          <base-popover
            :target-ref="`${user.id}-user-actions`"
            :open="isPopoverOpen && selectedUserId === user.id"
          > Hello!
          </base-popover>
        </base-cell>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </base-table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Bryan' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Pedro' },
      ],
      selectedUserId: null,
      isPopoverOpen: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    togglePopover(userId) {
      this.selectedUserId = userId;
      this.isPopoverOpen = !this.isPopoverOpen;
      console.log(this.$refs[`${userId}-user-actions`]); // Works, prints a Proxy object.
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Component E:

```js
<template>
  <div class="popover" v-show="open">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    targetRef: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    open: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$parent.$refs[this.targetRef]); // prints: undefined
    console.log(this.$parent.$refs); // prints: {}
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `this.$refs` instead of `this.$parent.$refs` should work

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim `this.$refs` returns `{}`